# How to conditionally define a typedef to be one of two types

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-traits

I'm sure that boost has some functions for doing this, but I don't know the relevant libraries well enough.  I have a template class, which is pretty basic, except for one twist where I need to define a conditional type. Here is the psuedo code for what I want

```
struct PlaceHolder {};

template <typename T>
class C {
    typedef (T == PlaceHolder ? void : T) usefulType;
};
```

How do I write that type conditional?

Comment: Interesting.  Under what circumstance would this be useful?  Can you provide an example.

Comment: Here was my example.  For one the template arguments, say TYPE, having value PlaceHolder means "turn off some feature".  There are a set of callbacks that have return type TYPE* that the natural meaning of turning off the feature is for the callbacks to have return type void.  usefulType is the return value for the callbacks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In modern C++ using the convenience templates [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```cpp
using usefulType = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, PlaceHolder>, void, T>;
```

In C++11, using only `typedef` and without the convenience aliases:

```cpp
typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, PlaceHolder>::value, void, T>::type
    usefulType;
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the principle you're after:

```
template< class T >
struct DefineMyTpe
{
  typedef T usefulType;
};

template<>
struct DefineMyType< PlaceHolder >
{
  typedef void usefulType;
};

template< class T > 
class C
{
  typedef typename DefineMyType< T >::usefulType usefulType;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template < typename T >
struct my_mfun : boost::mpl::if_
<
  boost::is_same<T,PlaceHolder>
, void
, T
> {};

template < typename T >
struct C { typedef typename my_mfun<T>::type usefulType; };
```

Comment: Code should be prefixed by 4 spaces. You can select text and click the 101010 button to do it in bulk.